# Replacing elements of irregular lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, replacement

I have a list dimensions {4, 2, ?, 3}. The ? can be any value from 1 to 5. Here's a simplified example:

```
data = {{{{-1,0.2,0}},{{-1,0.5,0}}},
{{{1,0.47,0},{-1,0.02,0},{1,1.0,0}},{{-1,0.12,0},{-1,0.11,0},{1,0.,0}}},
{{{1,0.1,0},{1,0.41,0},{-1,0.32,0}},{{1,0.02,0},{1,0.33,0},{1,0.01,0}}},
{{{-1,0.1,0},{-1,0.1,0}},{{1,0.41,0},{-1,0.6,0}}}};
```

I need to calculate an average progressively on the second value of the last dimension, which I've calculated this way so far:

```
second = Flatten[data[[All,All,All,2]]];
mean = Accumulate[second]/Range[Length[second]];
```

Now, I wish to replace the old values in data with this calculated average :

```
result = {{{{-1,0.2,0}},{{-1,0.35,0}}},
{{{1,0.39,0},{-1,0.2975,0},{1,0.438,0}},{{-1,0.385,0},{-1,0.345714,0},{1,0.3025,0}}},
{{{1,0.28,0},{1,0.293,0},{-1,0.295455,0}},{{1,0.2725,0},{1,0.276923,0},{1,0.257857,0}}},
{{{-1,0.247333,0},{-1,0.238125,0}},{{1,0.248235,0},{-1,0.267778,0}}}};
```

If the dimensions were known, it wouldn't be a problem. But they aren't. Also, my real dimensions are along the lines of {40, 10000, ?, 3}. I will be running this transformation thousands of time, so speed is key.

EDIT : This is what I've tried and it works, but I'm certain there is a better way

```
count = 0;
data[[All, All, All, 2]] = Table[++count;
mean[[count]], {n, 4}, {t, 2}, {l, Length[data[[n, t]]]}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a semi-imperative way to insert the `mean` values back into `data`:

```
Module[{i = 0}, MapAt[mean[[++i]] &, data, {All, All, All, 2}]]
```

Alternatively, we could perform the complete moving average operation semi-imperatively:

```
Module[{total = 0, count = 0}
, MapAt[(total += #)/(count += 1)&, data, {All, All, All, 2}]
]
```

Comment: I really like the moving average integrated in, thanks!

Comment: @Lokdal You are welcome.  It is common practice to wait a little while (say, a day or so) before accepting an answer to encourage others to submit even better answers.

Comment: I will do that!

Answer (score 5):

```
data[[All, All, All, 2]] = placeholder
ReplacePart[data, Thread[Position[data, placeholder] -> mean]]
```

Comment: Works great! But I'm selecting WReach's answer because it is faster and more elequent.

Comment: @Lokdal Agreed--it's a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
data[[;;, ;;, ;;, 2]] = Module[{i = 1}, Map[mean[[i++]] &, data[[;;, ;;, ;;, 2]], {-1}]]; 

data

{{{{-1, 0.2, 0}}, {{-1, 0.35, 0}}},   
 {{{1, 0.39, 0}, {-1, 0.2975,  0}, {1, 0.438, 0}},   
  {{-1, 0.385, 0}, {-1, 0.345714, 0}, {1, 0.3025, 0}}},   
 {{{1, 0.28, 0}, {1, 0.293, 0}, {-1, 0.295455,  0}},  
  {{1, 0.2725, 0}, {1, 0.276923, 0}, {1, 0.257857, 0}}},   
 {{{-1, 0.247333, 0}, {-1, 0.238125, 0}},   
  {{1, 0.248235, 0}, {-1, 0.267778, 0}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I do not know if you absolutely need to preserve the structure of your data. If not then consider using this:

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], mean, #[[All, 3]]}] &@Level[data, {-2}]

(* {{-1, 0.2, 0}, {-1, 0.35, 0}, {1, 0.39, 0}, {-1, 0.2975, 0}, {1, 0.438, 0},
{-1, 0.385, 0}, {-1, 0.345714, 0}, {1, 0.3025, 0}, {1,0.28, 0}, {1, 0.293, 0},
{-1, 0.295455, 0}, {1, 0.2725, 0}, {1,0.276923, 0}, {1, 0.257857, 0}, {-1, 0.247333, 0},
{-1, 0.238125, 0}, {1, 0.248235, 0}, {-1, 0.267778, 0}} *)
```